# Seeing the full text of a long notification

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 4.2-jelly-bean, notifications, notification-bar, 4.3-jelly-bean

I've got a notification on my phone where the length of the text exceeds the width of the screen and it doesn't wrap, just wanders off the edge. How can I see the full text of the notification?

I've seen a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12667286/902766) that long pressing for ~5 seconds shows it however all this does is bring up the `App Info` menu. Maybe on older versions of Android that didn't have the `App Info` menu this worked? Ideally looking for an answer that works on Ice Cream Sandwich and above (since I think that was when the `App Info` came about?) but I have a Nexus 4 running Jelly Bean 4.2.2 phone.

Here's the notification that I received. Hypothetical: *Why did I lose data connectivity? What did I do!?!*

[image]

Comment: Have you tried "pulling down" on the Notification? Perhaps with two fingers?

Comment: @AlEverett I accidentally got rid of it but I get them every week or so, I'll update when I next get one.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357450/android-multiline-notifications-notifications-with-longer-text
It may be only if the developers included the ability to read it. Also, in Android 4.1, larger notifications are allowed

Comment: @SSumner Yeah I saw that, but thanks. FYI I'm running a Jelly Bean 4.2.2 phone (updated question to add this) so should have the larger notifications.

Comment: This is a system notification, right? You can try turning the phone sideways, otherwise, I've never been able to read them

Comment: So some apps write their notification code to correctly utilize the "expandable notifications" feature of later versions of Android. Clearly, this one doesn't. I think we should treat this question as "How can I see the full text of the notification [that doesn't use the expandable notifications feature]?"

Comment: what you can do is open up an app like Clock, enable screen rotation and hold your phone horizontally. Will show a greater part of the notiviation... - I cannot believe this is an actual issue. Why is there  no fix for that

Answer (score 6):

In 4.2.x Jelly Bean you can [pinch-zoom or two-finger glide in order to toggle between base and expanded [notification] layouts](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html). Not all notifications can be expanded, however. The next time the notification appears try using two fingers to "pull" the notification down into an expanded layout.

Comment: Worth trying, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: didn't worked for me too ! I am using Android 5.0.2 CM12.

Comment: Works for Android 7 on my Galaxy S8.

Answer (score 2):

You can expand it by touching the notification and dragging down. The touch part of the gesture is very brief, so it feels like a single, quick gesture. This works on Android 7.1, I can't confirm for earlier versions myself, but would be interested I hearing if it works in earlier versions also.

Android 7.1 also shows a little caret (arrow) pointing down to the right of the notification time in the title area. Clicking the title area expands and collapses the notification, and you'll see the caret switch from pointing up to down.

Comment: The little caret works on Android 11.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works for all notifications, or 4.x as originally asked, but I am using Lollipop (5.0.2) and just double-tapped a notification (from Google Play Store, about not being able to update an app because of insufficient storage space). It came up as a dialog box with the full text.

Comment: Didn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

On my Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 5.0.1 I can just "pull down" the notification (using one finger) or pinch-zoom it (using two fingers) to see the full text:

- first, pull down the notification bar
- then pull down the single notification, where the text is cropped

I don't know whether this is specific for Samsung's TouchWiz or if it's a standard Android feature. I just tried it with various notifications from Spotify, Gmail, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, if pinch zoom and two-finger glide din't work, try to rotate screen to landscape mode by switching on the auto-rotate feature and read the notification in Landscape. It may help you read the notifications most of the times. Because clicking the nofication will open the specific app and you wont be able to read it until it shows up next time by itself and long press can show menus to turn off notifications compeletly. So the auto-rotate worked in my case(Not all the times but most of the times in my Lollipop).