# Is there any way to read long notifications in Android KitKat?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notifications, notification-bar

Some apps will create notifications that are too long to be read on the screen (horizontally or vertically).  They get truncated and you can't read the end.

Is there a way to read notifications that are too long to fit in the notification drop-down list?

Please ensure your answers are specific for Android KitKat.

For Android Jelly Bean, see [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47578/seeing-the-full-text-of-a-long-notification).

Comment: Have you tried swiping down the notification?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seeing the full text of a long notification](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47578/seeing-the-full-text-of-a-long-notification)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried pulling down the notification using two fingers? If that doesn't work then it maybe that the specific app doesn't support it.
Not all apps support viewing the entire text in the notifications panel.

Comment: Wish the os davedthe texts somewhere. So we can read later and full; till 1,000 new ones in queue.